# Django save variable name in db

Tags: python, django

I am writing somekind of custom cms and I need to save variable names

For example user can write this in textarea(and I need to save exactly the same phrase to db with this syntax):

`My dog is {{dog_name}}`

And somewhere on `dog_settings.html` page he can set `dog_name=Max`

And when he clicks on result button which is called show me combination of template 
 he has written and settings:

I need to show him result string:

`My dog is Max`

How do I do this?

*He can then rename his dog to `Jack` and the result needs to be renamed: `My dog is Jack`

*He can also change the order of the words or the whole phrase, `{{dog_name}} is awesome` and the result will be `Jack is awesome`

Also he can use html in textarea, for example `<p>{{dog_name}} is awesome</p>`
So as a result I need to show him what is called raw html but also insert real dog_name. And moreover `dog_name` can be also html like `dog_name=<span>Jack</span>`. So the result will be `<p><span>Jack</span> is awesome</p>`

Comment: Forget about variable names, this is just a (partial) template. So just render it: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/templates/api/#rendering-a-context

Answer (score 0):

A way you can do this is by using regEx. so you can extract everything inside {{ and }}, then save both key and value. Here an example:
Your models should have something like this:

```
class textArea(models.Model):
      text = models.TextField(max_length=50)

class options(modesl.Model):
      op_key = models.CharField(max_length=50)
      op_val = models.CharField(max_length=50)
      text = models.ForeignKey(textArea)
```

and in your view:

```
this_text = textArea.objects.get(pk=3)
text_options = options.objects.filter(text=this_text)
```

then you can simply replace keys with values like this ( in view ).

```
for each_option in text_options:
    this_text.text.replace("{{" + str(each_option.op_key) + "}}", each_option.op_val)
```

and now you have replaced string.
and in another view you can extract this keys from text.